# Sum of int elements in list and vector using single function in Scala

Tags: scala

How to make this code work?

```
sealed abstract class Addable[A] {
  def sum(el: Seq[A]): A
}

class MyAddable[A]() extends Addable[A] {
  override def sum(el: Seq[A]): A = {
    el.sum

  }
}

val myvec = Vector(1, 2, 3)
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3)

val inst = new MyAddable

val res0 = inst.sum(mylist) // should return 6
val res1 = inst.sum(myvec)  // should return 6

println(s"res0 = $res0")
println(s"res1 = $res1")
```

I want to pass a generic data type (Vector/List[Int]) and get a sum of it's elements using the described signatures and code structure.

At the moment I am getting:

```
found   : immutable.this.List[scala.this.Int]
 required: Seq[scala.this.Nothing]
```

[Scalafiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/gpuwzf6/0)

Comment: How do you expect to sum the elements of a **List** of **Doubles** or of **Strings** or of **Maps**, etc? Do you want to make it work for all numeric data types? or for any type to which you can define an `add` operation?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I want to make it work for `Int`. Edited the question

Comment: If you only want to sum sequence of `Ints` why do you need the generic `A` at all?? Or its your Addable for **Ints** and there is other Addable for **Floats**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sealed abstract class Addable[A] {
  def sum(el: Seq[A]): A
}

class MyAddable[A: Numeric]() extends Addable[A] {
  override def sum(el: Seq[A]): A = {
    el.sum
  }
}

val myvec = Vector(1, 2, 3)
val mylist = List(1, 2, 3)

val inst = new MyAddable[Int]()

val res0 = inst.sum(mylist)
val res1 = inst.sum(myvec)

println(s"res0 = $res0")
println(s"res1 = $res1")
```

Answer (score 3):

The specific error is here:

```
val inst = new MyAddable
```

which should be

```
val inst = new MyAddable[Int]()
```

`MyAddable` is generic but you are not specifying a type, so it is assuming `Nothing`, hence the error message.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I gave it a +. However, I marked another answer as it also fixed the follow-up error

Answer (score 1):

```
import cats.{Semigroup}
import cats.implicits._

// Specify a generic Reduce Function. Use Contravariant parameter to support reduce on derived types   
trait Reduce[-F[_]] {
  def reduce[A](fa:F[A])(f:(A,A) => A):A
}    

object Reduce {      
  implicit val SeqReduce  = new Reduce[Seq] {
    def reduce[A] (data:Seq[A])(f:(A,A) => A ):A = data reduce f 
  }

  implicit val OptReduce  = new Reduce[Option] {
    def reduce[A] (data:Option[A])(f:(A,A) => A ):A = data reduce f
  }        
}

// Generic sum function
def sum[A:Semigroup, F[_]](container: F[A])(implicit red:Reduce[F]):A = {
  red.reduce(container)(Semigroup.combine(_,_))
} 

  val myvec   = Vector(1, 2, 3)
  val mylist  = List  (1, 2, 3)

  val mymap   = Map ( 1 -> "one",
                      2 -> "two",
                      3 -> "three"
                    )
  val myopt   = Some(1)

  val res0  = sum(myvec)
  val res1  = sum(mylist)
  val res2  = sum(myopt)      

  println(s"res0 = $res0")
  println(s"res1 = $res1")
  println(s"res2 = $res2")
```

This gets a little more complicated for Maps